# Retrieve data without duplication SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to retrieve data "all columns" from one table without duplication, I used `Select count (distinct column_name)` to retrieve total number of rows without duplication and it was 14000 rows, every time I tried to retrieve the 14000 rows of "data", I got the full table with 20000 rows.

This the SQL statements that I used

```
select * 
from Table_name 
where [Column_name] in (select distinct [Column_name] from Table_name)
```

I also tried

```
select * 
from Table_name 
where [Column_name] in (select  [Column_name] 
                        from Table_name 
                        group by [Column_name] )
```

and I still get 20000 rows.

Note: the data type of this column is `nvarchar(255)`

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try `select distinct * from Table_name`

Comment: What do you mean "without duplication"?

Comment: Which 'version' of the duplicates do you want to get? If all of the duplicates have the same values (well why do they?), your friend is DISTINCT. If they are different, then which is the one what you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per column, then you need to do a bit more work.  `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all the columns.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column_name order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table_name t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will return an arbitrary row for each value in `column_name`.